# Query sysdate against field in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT LAST_MAINTAIN, PLANE_ID
FROM PLANE
WHERE MONTHS BETWEEN(
      (TO_DATE('sysdate',        'MM/DD/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('LAST_MAINTAIN',  'MM/DD/YYYY')))
       >24;
```

I am trying to select Last_Maintain, a date field, from the Plane table and return results that have 2 years between today's date and the last maintenance. Does anyone know what is wrong? I have a feeling I am using months between incorrectly but I'm not sure. Thanks

Edit: Adjusted location of sysdate and Last_Maintain, still erroring out saying I'm missing a parentheses (right), even though I went through all my parentheses without seeing one missing.

Edit2: Tried out

```
SELECT *
  FROM plane
WHERE MONTHS BETWEEN (sysdate, last_maintain ) > 24;
```

Still telling me I need more parentheses.

Edit3: Problem is resolved, here is the final code that worked:

```
SELECT *
  FROM plane
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN (sysdate, last_maintain) > 24;
```

Comment: That looks like Oracle syntax.

Comment: Are you querying a MySQL database using Oracle SQL Developer? If that's the case, you probably need to use MySQL syntax :-!

Comment: Changed the tag, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date` does not make any sense. It converts the `date` into a `varchar` which is then converted into a `date` (which it was to begin with). Also column reference must not be put into single quotes `'LAST_MAINTAIN'` is a string constant, `LAST_MAINTAIN` is a column identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't call `to_date` on a date.  `to_date` converts a string to a date.  It would only make sense to pass a string to `to_date`.
- sysdate is a function that returns a `date`.  That is very, very different from a literal string `sysdate`

You probably want

```
SELECT *
  FROM plane
 WHERE months_between( sysdate, last_maintain ) > 24
```

Comment: Tried that out, still telling me that I missed a parentheses (I also changed months_ between to Months Between and removed the extra parentheses by the > sign.

Comment: @TomAnderson - you should have removed the extra closing parenthesis, but you should not have changed [`months_between`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions102.htm) back to `months between`; the former is a function name, the latter is not.

Comment: Apologies for the stray close paren.  That's been removed.

Comment: Thank you! Saved my project I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

MONTHS_BETWEEN returns the result as first - second, so in your case, all values are < 0.  Put sysdate first.

From Oracle doc:

"If date1 is earlier than date2, then the result is negative"